# How does encryption works between aws ELB and instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

For an aws classic load balancer with a https listener, the aws ELB docs says that "If the HTTPS listener sends requests to the instances on port 443, communication from the load balancer to the instances is encrypted". I want to know that how communication between the ELB and the instances can be encrypted without having an ssl certificate on the instances and if this communication is encrypted then which keys are used to encrypt it? and how does the instances decrypt the data at their end?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to install an SSL certificate on each of the instances. It could be the same certificate you have installed on the ELB (if it wasn't an ACM generated certificate) or it could be another SSL certificate or a self-signed SSL certificate.

Whatever SSL certificate is installed on the instance is what will be used to encrypt communication between the ELB and the instance.

Comment: When we make an instance accept traffic on port 443 it is not mandatory to install a ssl certificate on it and their docs says that if the instance receives traffic on port 443 then the communication is encrypted. I configured my instance security group to accept only https traffic on port 443 without installing an ssl on it and still hitting the load balancer on https was serving me the expected web page. thanks for answering but I am still not clear about it.

Comment: The docs are misleading. You are seeing SSL communication between your web browser and your load balancer. The communication between the load balancer and the server can be on any port. If you want the communication between the load balancer and the server to be encrypted you have to install an SSL certificate on the server.